# Using Summary-Details for a collapsible menu

Tags: css, collapsable

I know this should be simple, but I'm not a coder and have spent a dozen hours trying to do something that should be simple.  I have several topics that I need to expand or collapse (accordian).

I found on this site using Summary-Details should work, and it kinda does but backwards.  It works fine on my blog development, but when you enter the page all of the details are expanded by default, defeating the purpose of trying to make the page look less cluttered.

Here's the code I'm using which has some formatting in it making it look ugly.

```
<details open="">
   <summary style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family: 
      &quot;arial&quot; , &quot;helvetica&quot; , sans-serif;"><b>Summary Goes 
      Here</b><span style="font-size: xx-small;">(details)</span></span>
   </summary>
   <div style="text-align: left;">
      <span style="font-family: &quot;arial&quot; , &quot;helvetica&quot; , sans- 
         serif;">Detail Content Goes Here</span>
   </div>
</details>
```

I have tested this using Chrome (desktop and mobile) and Safari, both with the same results.

Comment: Is this all of the relevant code?

Comment: we are missing elements to help you, like the css, and possibly the javascript.

Comment: Yaakov/Neil,  I don't know what other piece of code you might be looking for.  This was all I added to create the accordian feature, but the entire page can be seen here so you could look at the full source.  

https://givethischristmasaway.blogspot.com/p/angeltree-sandbox.html

Answer (score 0):

`open=""` is the same as `open="true"` or `open="open"`

This sort of attribute is always `true` if it's present, regardless of its value - if you want them closed to start with it must removed from the code.